# O Firebase não permite usar get e set nas informações de query?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Estou tentando utilizar os métodos get e set com javascript nas querys do firebase..

Ele não me permite utilizar o get() pois ele não acessa o array e fica dando erro ou lenght 0.

Porque acontece isso e como deve ser feito?

Código exemplo:

```
// BUSCAR NO FIREBASE
function getMarkersFB(){
    let arrMarkers = new Array();
    let databaseROOT = firebase.database().ref('aliansce/maps/');
    databaseROOT.on('child_added', (mapsKeys) => {

        let databaseMAPS = databaseROOT.child('' + mapsKeys.key + '/markers/');
        databaseMAPS.on('child_added', (markersKey) => {

            let databaseMARKERS = databaseROOT.child('' + mapsKeys.key + '/markers/' + markersKey.key);
            databaseMARKERS.on('value', (markersChildsKeys) => {
                //console.log(markersChildsKeys.val())
                arrMarkers.push({
                    id: markersChildsKeys.val().markerID,
                    points: markersChildsKeys.val().markerPoints,
                    title: markersChildsKeys.val().markerTitle
                });

            });
        });
    });

    setMarker(arrMarkers)
    console.log(getMarker())
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu der o seguinte codigo ele não encontra o tal valor, fora da função do firebase.

```
console.log(getMarker()[0].id)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: 1. Não retorna nada pois a função não retorna nada, fora que o é um método assíncrono o do Firebase; 2. A variável `arrMarkers` é local, só funciona dentro da função `getMaker`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr eu já utilizei como global, dai não funciona.